# unable to download box - 'An error occurred while downloading the remote file.'

Tags: curl, vagrant

I'm trying to download a box, and run into the following error:

```
snowch:~/Demo$ vagrant box add zyga/ubuntu-precise-desktop-i386
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'zyga/ubuntu-precise-desktop-i386'
    box: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/zyga/ubuntu-precise-desktop-i386
==> box: Adding box 'zyga/ubuntu-precise-desktop-i386' (v1.0) for provider: virtualbox
    box: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/zyga/boxes/ubuntu-precise-desktop-i386/versions/1.0/providers/virtualbox.box
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

transfer closed with 1403398904 bytes remaining to read
```

If I try to download with curl, I get:

```
snowch:~/Demo$ curl --insecure -L -v https://vagrantcloud.com/zyga/boxes/ubuntu-precise-desktop-i386/versions/1.0/providers/virtualbox.box
...
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* transfer closed with 1403398904 bytes remaining to read
* Closing connection 1
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
curl: (18) transfer closed with 1403398904 bytes remaining to read
```

My vagrant version is:

```
snowch:~/Demo$ vagrant --version
Vagrant 1.7.3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I can reproduce this with the same box and vagrant 1.7.2. But I can still download other boxes from Atlas. I assume that there is a broken binary behind the box.

Comment: Thanks for trying this and feeding back your outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check what Vagrant is doing with:

```
export VAGRANT_LOG=debug
```

I think this might be a bug in atlas. I would ping hashicorp.

The full command that is used to download box looks like this:

```
curl -q \
--fail \
--location \
--max-redirs 10 \
--user-agent Vagrant/1.7.2 \
--continue-at - \
--output test.box \
https://atlas.hashicorp.com/zyga/boxes/ubuntu-precise-desktop-i386/versions/1.0/providers/virtualbox.box
```